# Compare two lists of colors

Tags: c#

Lets say I have two lists of colors and I need to compare them. I have a function of comparing colors but I'm a little bit confused of types which function gets. How to cast them?

```
public bool AreColorsSimilar(Color c1, Color c2, int tolerance)
{
    return Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) < tolerance &&
           Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G) < tolerance &&
           Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) < tolerance;
}
```

Here is my first list:

```
public static List<Color> PaletteOfSeasons()
{
    List<Color> springColors = new List<Color>();

    springColors.Add(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#80a44c"));
    springColors.Add(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#b4cc3a"));


    return springColors;
}
```

And in another list I'm pulling pixels from image:

```
public static IEnumerable<Color> GetPixels(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            yield return pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

And question is, how can I compare this colors ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the *result* of the comparison? Are you trying to *sort* the `List`? Do you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: Side-note: why do you have a method that takes a `List<Color>` which will be recreated and then being returned from the method? It doesn't need the parameter.

Comment: I want to find similar colors comparing my static colors with colors from any image

Comment: Note that the comparison function cannot be used for sorting since it only tells you if two colors are "equal" or not.  You'd need some sort of function that tells if one color is "greater than", "less than", or "equal" to another.

Comment: @igor1990 So you want to see if each pixel is "similar to" any of the colors in `PaletteOfSeasons`?

Comment: @D Stanley yes, I'm trying to do exactly this

Comment: Just a fyi, `Bitmap.GetPixel()` can be *relatively* slow. If possible you may want to look in to using `Bitmap.LockBits()`

Comment: @igor1990 to check each pixel's similarity, you will have a boolean result as many as the number of your pixels (Width x Height of your picture), is this what you really want? Also, do you consider the transparency parameter for the checking? Or is it purely image color?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right:

```
var springColors = null;
springColors = PaletteOfSeasons(springColors);

var similarColors = GetPixels(bitmap).Intersect(springColors, new ColorComparer(tolerance));
```

And you need this class:

```
public class ColorComparer : IEqualityComparer<Color> 
{
    private _tolerance;

    public ColorComparer(int tolerance)
    {
        _tolerance = tolerance;
    }

    public bool Equals(Color x, Color y)
    {
        return AreColorsSimilar(x, y, _tolerance);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo x)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    private bool AreColorsSimilar(Color c1, Color c2, int tolerance)
    {
        return Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) < tolerance &&
           Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G) < tolerance &&
           Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) < tolerance;
    }
}
```

P.S. Your method PaletteOfSeasons is a little confusing. Passing list to method foolishly.

P.P.S. Use Bitmap.LockBits() to increase code performance.

P.P.P.S. Such implementation of GetHashCode isn't good. But in our situation it is OK.

Comment: I also though about using an IEqualityComparer, but due to the problematic `GetHashCode` I didn't use it. Your *implementation* full-fills all desired needs, but if you use it in an Dictionary its performance falls down to O(n) which is quite bad. So IMHO either implement a better GetHashCode (which is tricky) or use the method more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare all pixels of the bitmap with all the colors in the palettes:

```
foreach(var pixel in GetPixels(myBitmap))
{
    foreach(var candidate in paletteOfSeasons)
    {
        if(AreColorsSimilar(pixel, candidate, 42)
        {
            // Hooray, found some similar colors.
        }
    }
}
```